# How do I change the colour of the text in my Flutter AppBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Widget getMain() {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
    title: Text("Guide.", style: textStyleBold),
  ), //AppBar
```

I have set the appbar's background colour to a dark grey and the colour of the text doesn't stand out very well being black. I thought it would be a quick fix to change it to white but I'm having no luck. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is `textStyleBold`?

Comment: you can change it in the `textStyleBold`. that's where the color is probably defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a color to your Text widget using the `TextStyle` object:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
        title: Text(
          "Guide.",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.amber,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: yourBodyWidget,
    );
}
```

Please check [TextStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html) to customise your text further.

Answer (score -1):

```
appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
    title: Text("Guide.", style: TextStyle(color: yourColor)),
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.